# How to add/modify query params from a root service during initialization?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to update one query param of the URL from a root/singleton service. This services responsibility is to preserve some shared state in the URL for deep linking.

The problem is that e.g. [ActiveRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) does not work as this service is not bound to a route and always returns "/". Also using Angular router.url doesn't work as on construction time of the service, this route url is "/" as well.

I found a way (see below) to do this as follows but it looks *very* hacky and I am looking for a cleaner way to do it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService implements OnDestroy {

(...)

private updateUrlOnDataChange() {
    this.dataChanges.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe((data) => {
      const segments = this.router.parseUrl(this.location.path()).root.children['primary']
        ?.segments;
      const pathFragments = (segments || []).map((segment) => segment.path);
      const params = this.router.parseUrl(this.location.path()).queryParams;
      params['data'] = JSON.stringify(data);
      this.router.navigate(pathFragments, {
        queryParams: params,
      });
    });
  }

}
```

So, actually, what I would like to do is just

```
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: params,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      });
```

Which doesn't work. It would work when executing it from a component that is bound to the leaf route segment which this service is not.

Maybe this is just due to a lack of knowledge about the [Router API](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) but I couldn't find any information relevant to my problem in the docs.

**[EDIT]**

It appears, that I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157). The solution proposed below works if the query params are updated after the application is completely initialised (including the Router). This is not yet the case when pasting in a deep link that updates internal state which then updates the URL params again. At that point in time, the router / ActivatedRoute has not yet been initialized with the actual URL from the browser and just returns "/" with no queryParams.

In the linked git hub issue, there are a couple solutions proposed.

**[EDIT 2]**

The suggested solution works *unless* you try to update the query params while being in the constructor of a root service. At that time, the router is not initialized.

So I introduced an observable to the QueryParamsService that other services could use to determine when the router is initialized:

```
export class QueryParamsService {
  public initialized$: Observable<void>;
  private readonly initializedSubject: ReplaySubject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);
  private routerInitialized = false;

  constructor(private readonly router: Router, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.initialized$ = this.initializedSubject.asObservable();
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event: RouterEvent) => !!event && event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.routerInitialized = true;
        this.initializedSubject.next(undefined);
      });
  }

(...)
```

I also use `this.routerInitialized` to throw an error when query params are modifed before initialization is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QueryParamService {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  public addQueryParam(paramName: string, paramValue: string): void {
    const queryParams = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams };
    queryParams[paramName] = paramValue;
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams });
  }
  
  public modifyQueryParam(paramName: string, paramValue: string): void {
    const queryParams = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams };
    if (queryParams[paramName]) {
      queryParams[paramName] = paramValue;
      this.router.navigate([], { queryParams });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I tried this already and it works except for the initialization phase. When we paste in a deep link, let's say `/foo/bar?data=1`, and add console logs to the addQueryParam method we get: 
```this.location.path() = /foo/bar?data=1
this.route.snapshot.url = []
this.router.url = '/'``` 
So when deep link is pasted in the browser, the we update the state of `data` which then fires the observable that will add the queryParam (again). However, at that time as you can see the Angular managed urls are not set yet.